# How does .NET know where to look for extension methods?

Tags: c#, extension-methods

I believe I understand the concept of extension methods, except one detail. It seems you can create a random (static) class with a random `static` method using `this` on a parameter. I believe this parameter has to match the type of class you want to extend (or one it's inheriting from).
An example:

```
public static class MyExtendedMethods
{
    public static int square(this int num)
    {
        int result = 0;
        result = num * num;
        return result;
    }
}

class Program
{
    static void Main(string[] args)
    {
        int myNum = 3;
        myNum = myNum.square();
        Console.WriteLine(myNum);
    }
}
```

How does .NET know where to find this class and method (`MyExtendedMethods.square()`)? I don't see the classes related in any way. Is it looking through all classes in the project for a possible extension?

Comment: The static class must be in an accessible namespace.

Comment: I'm just guessing here, but since C# has a compiler that checks ALL code before you even get to run your application, it seems logical (or at least plausible) that the compiler does some form of extension method aggregation so it doesn't have to keep looking in every possible location every time. Since it has to traverse all used code anyway, there's no reason not to remember when you saw an extension method. But this is just an educated guess, rather than a knowledgeable answer.

Comment: http://www.hanselman.com/blog/HowDoExtensionMethodsWorkAndWhyWasANewCLRNotRequired.aspx

Comment: @abhitalks That is a totally different question...

Comment: @abhitalks I think it's only a duplicate if the questions mean the same thing, not if answers for one happen to also answer the other

Comment: @abhitalks Don't blindly mark as a duplicate, check the question title *and* body before assuming it's the same question.

Comment: .NET does not look for extension methods, language compilers do. The rules for [C#](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms228593.aspx) and VB.NET are well-explained in their respective specifications. (Note: Looking for extension methods is different than defining extension methods. They are in different sections of the specifications [C# 5.0 section 7.6.5.2 Extension method invocations, section 10.6.9 Extension methods.)

Comment: "Is it looking through all classes in the project for a possible extension?" No, the C# compiler does not have the concept of a project. That's an IDE thing. Intellisense and similar IDE tools (ReSharper, etc) might look through your solution for you and suggest what could be made to work at compile time.

Comment: Correcting terms in your question: `this` parameter has to match the type of _type_ you want to extend. A type is an interface or a class.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

It looks for static classes inside the namespaces you declared at the top of your file, like 'using System.Linq;'
(if it cannot find anything in the current namespace)
Then it simply replaces the call with

```
MyExtendedMethods.square
```